# How to get perpendicular line to an edge of a polygon.

Tags: geometry

This is a pretty basic geometry question, but I couldn't find an answer clear enough for me on Google (I don't know much about math).

Let's say I have a rectangle. I have the coordinates for the four vertices, thus I have the angles of the rectangle and the lengths of the edges.

I need to find one perpendicular line for each of the shape's edges. How can I do that, the simplest way?

Thanks

Edit:

What I mean: I need to know how to find the lines that come out of the rectangle's edges.

[image]

Comment: Will these perpendicular lines need to be different from the other sides of the rectangle?  In particular, by "rectangle" I assume that you mean "a four-sided two-dimensional figure in the plane having all interior angles congruent to $90^\circ$"...

Comment: Please see my edit, it explains what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

With a straightedge and compass, the lines specified can be constructed as follows:

- Take the compass, set the size to draw circles slightly larger than half the length of the long side of the rectangle
- With this fixed size, draw four circles, each one centered on one corner of the rectangle
- Take the straightedge and line it up with the locations where the circles intersect in four collinear locations
- Draw the **perpendicular bisectors** of each side of the rectangle where the straightedge crosses it

See the picture below for more info.

[image: Construct Perpendicular Bisector]

The colored circles are centered on each of the four corners of the rectangle; the long sides have closer-together circle intersections so it is possible to see all of them and easy to connect them with a line.  For the shorter sides, it may be necessary to construct a second set of four circles that are smaller and have closer-together intersections, depending on the size of the piece of paper you are using.

Alternatively, it is possible to construct these lines using midpoints.  If the four corners of the rectangle are $A,B,C,D$ where $\exists x_A,y_A\in\Bbb R: A=(x_A,y_A)$, etc., then the midpoints of each side are connectable as perpendicular bisectors as well.  Let $M_{XY}$ be the midpoint of side $XY$, then we have coordinates:

$$M_{AB}=(\frac {x_A+x_B}2,\frac {y_A+y_B}2)\\
M_{BC}=(\frac {x_B+x_C}2,\frac {y_B+y_C}2)\\
M_{CD}=(\frac {x_C+x_D}2,\frac {y_C+y_D}2)\\
M_{DA}=(\frac {x_D+x_A}2,\frac {y_D+y_A}2)$$

It is further possible to create these as lines extending beyond each side, using the generic line formula

$$(E_x-S_x)(y-S_y)=(E_y-S_y)(x-S_x)$$

Where $E,S$ are "starting" and "ending" points of the lines in question.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I need to get the *angle* of the perpendicular line to each edge. How can I do that?

Comment: It is the same angle as the adjacent side.  The line perpendicular to side $AB$ has angle congruent to the side $BC$, and so on.

Comment: What if I have a line and I know it's angle. If I simply add 90 degrees to it, will I get the angle of it's perpendicular line?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Okay thanks :) .

Answer (score 1):

EDIT1

[image: Geom Constrn]

Deleted an earlier computational given solution for this construction: Choose a radius more than half the larger side length of the rectangle and draw four circles centered at each corner of the rectangle with this same radius. Join either the outermost (or innermost) points of circle intersection lying on opposite sides of rectangle as shown by the required purple perpendicular bisectors.